# installing jmf in linux

Tags: software-installation

i have downloaded the jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i589.bin and i tried to run but it shows that

```
Do you agree to the above license terms? [yes or no] 
y

Permit recording from an applet? (see readme.html) [yes or no] 
y

Permit writing local files from an applet? (recommend no, see readme.html) [yes or no] 
y
Unpacking...
Extracting...
/home/hm/Downloads/jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin: 297: /home/hm/Downloads/jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin: ./install.sfx.5532: not found
JavaSound Capture Supported = true
JavaSoundAuto: Committed ok
Done.
```

please help me as guys what to do next or what i did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this tutorial:
[Install Java Media Framework in Ubuntu](https://estebanfuentealba.wordpress.com/2009/03/22/instalar-java-media-framework-jmf-en-ubuntu/)

If the problem persists, then try executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs -y
```

If this prompts an error, replace the command with this:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 -y
```

Good luck!